Derived class as argument of OpenCL kernel function
I am trying to compile the following OpenCL kernel code with clang-16:
clang-16 -cl-std=clc++2021 -c -emit-llvm -target spir64 -Xclang -finclude-default-header \
  -o /workspace/test/mySamplekernelFile.bc mySamplekernelFile.cpp

Source code of mySamplekernelFile.cpp:
class StructA
{
    float f1;
    float f2;
};

class StructB : public StructA
{
    double d3;
    float f4;
};


__kernel void myFunction(
    const int myInt,
    __global float* myFloat,
    __global StructB* myStructB)
{
   // do something
}

But I got following error message:
test.cpp:17:23: error: '__global StructB *__private' cannot be used as the type of a kernel parameter     __global StructB* myStructB)
I know that not all C++ features are sopported by C++ for OpenCL. But in this case, what is the issue that preventing me from using this derived class as argument of kernel function?
